# Hide Discount Code Input Field in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm looking for the location of the discount code input field in the theme code, I can't quite find it. I need to hide the discount code input field for users with a certain tag on them. I'm thinking of just a simple conditional rendering for the discount code input field.

If anyone can provide insight on where that code lies, or an alternative to prevent users with a specific tag from using discounts, that would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about the discount code field on checkout page ? 

if YES - It can only be accessed from checkout.liquid file in the theme editor.
if NO - Please share a screenshot of the page, where that discount input is.

Answer (score 0):

You can install your own Shopify Function in the store, and that Function can alter how Checkout works, specifically to ensure Discounts are done the way you want. Look into that if you want to alter the way your store works.

The logic you can read into this is as follows. If the customer qualifies for a discount, your function allows the provided discount to work. If not, the function ignores whatever discount code the customer tries.

In other words, you don't worry about show/hide on the discount code input box. It is programmatically used.

Comment: You got a link or an example?

Comment: Sadly, I will refrain from the oldest acronym in the book, one we should all know and live by, and simply abide by the StackOverflow rules of not posting links. You have to understand Shopify provides EXCELLENT documentation on this topic, with everything you need to know, handed to you on a platter.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to hide discount coupon box with functions as far as I have read. I was wondering if you know something special.